# JQuery/Javascript code doesn't enter 'each'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't really understand why my code doesn't enter the 'each' loop in the 'klikzoekknop' function. I can get the text value of the span, en the li does exist inside .chosen-results, so I don't really get it. The function is entered, I can for example use an `alert(selectedText);` Changing the submit to a normal button doesn't work.

The following is my Javascript/Jquery function:

```
function klikzoekknop(element){
    var selectedText = $(".chosen-single span").text();
    $(".chosen-results li").each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
};
```

The following is my HTML:

```
<form class="zoekform">
<input type="text" class="inputzoeken" name="zoekterm" placeholder="Zoeken...">
<select class="menu-chosen" name="kolomnaam" style="display: none;">
 <option value="incident">Incident</option>
 <option value="melddatum">Melddatum</option>
 <option value="gewijzigd">Gewijzigd op</option>
 <option value="extern">nummer</option>
 <option value="melder">Melder</option>
 <option value="type">Type</option>
 <option value="status">Status</option>
 <option value="omschrijving">Korte omschrijving</option>
</select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 128px;" title="">
 <a tabindex="-1" class="chosen-single">
  <span>Incident</span>
  <div>
   <b></b>
  </div>
 </a>
 <div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
   <input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="">
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results">
   <li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Incident</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Melddatum</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Gewijzigd op</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">nummer</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">Melder</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">Type</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="6">Status</li>
   <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="7">Korte omschrijving</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="klikzoekknop(this);" class="zoekknop" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: working check at http://jsfiddle.net/36t7zrju/ one possible reason you are missing script tag for javascript code

Comment: I see, but why not in here than?

Comment: can you show complete page source

Answer (score 2):

Your form is being `submit` before the `click` event completes. Use a standard `type="button"` for the element and then submit the form manually using `$('.zoekform').submit();`

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. The function is entered and I can, for example, alert the value of selectedText.

Comment: Diagnostics are fine, but as a solution I would rather suggest to use form.onsubmit than to use a different button. After all, a form can also be submitted through hotkeys, bypassing the button altogether, so your solution will allow for undesired behaviour.

Comment: @GolezTrol that's a good point. The function klikzoekknop will need calling within the `$('.zoekform').on('submit', function() {});` event listener function.

Comment: I changed the submit button to an input with type button, but that didn't solve the problem.